# How do I make an algorithm to prioritize by date and / or source?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm little stuck with this algorithm that I have to do in sql.
I have in a table product codes, product name , supplier and the product update date.
I need to prioritize the products by provider and date as the case may be.For Example, if a product has 1,2 and / or 3 as a supplier, the product with the highest update rate must be selected. 
But if the product has a supplier 4, 5 and / or 6, the product with the lowest number of the supplier must be selected.

Make this query that is in a cursor if the query is greater than or equal to 1 the data the first data in the row is inserted into another table. It is what I have for the moment

```
    SELECT @QUERY = count (*)  from (
SELECT TOP 1 
   code_product,update_date,supplier,name_product 
FROM Product_updates
WHERE ( supplier = 1 OR supplier =2 OR supplier = 3 ) and code_product 
    = @code_product and code_product is not null 
order by  update_date DESC 
) a
```

Practical example, here is the table

```
    code_product    name_product    supplier    update_date
    1313                   A            1       11-03-2019
    1313                   A            3       12-10-2019
    1313                   A            2       11-10-2019
    1313                   A            6       13-10-2019
    1515                   B            5       13-10-2019
    1515                   B            4       13-02-2018
    1515                   B            6       15-04-2019
```

and expected result

```
    code_product    name_product    supplier    update_date
    1313                 A               3        12-10-2019
    1515                 B               4        13-02-2018
```

Please help, Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by 'lowest number of supplier'? These numbers are IDs of suppliers or ranks?

Comment: @mohkamfer is a ranks

Comment: Why not just order by additional supplier? in ascending order.

So it becomes ORDER BY update_date DESC, supplier ASC

Answer (score 0):

You would use `row_number()` for prioritization:

```
select pu.*
from (select pu.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code_product
                                order by (case when supplier in (1, 2, 3) then update_date desc,
                                         update_date asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from product_updates pu
     ) pu
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do somewhat manipulating the supplier values via case

```
    Select code_product, name_product, 
      Case when 1 =max(Case 
      when 
              supplier in 
          (1,2,3) 
        then 1
         else 2 end) then max(date) 
        Else min(date) end
      from table group by code_product, 
      name_product, (Case when 1 
         =max(Case 
            when 
              supplier in 
          (1,2,3)
        then 1
         else 2 end) then max(date) 
        Else min(date) end)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Updated. Check now